# Can sending msg.value to owner be dangerous?

Tags: transfer

I have an erc721 token with a payable function added to it. It just needs to mint the token and then owner.transfer(msg.value).
Assuming owner is my own address which I used to deploy the contract.

Comment: Define "dangerous". `owner.transfer(msg.value)` will do precisely what it says. From the point of view of "can `owner` lose money", then no, it is not dangerous, since `transfer` can only take positive values. Of course, it's up to you to make sure that `owner` is precisely the address you intend it to be, and your users to make sure that `msg.value` is precisely what _they_ intend it to be.

Other than that, as long as your ERC721 token doesn't represent a contract on anyone's life, I don't see anything dangerous here ;-)

Comment: Thank you, yes I meant dangerous in the view of can the owner lose money. This answers my question.